# display.newText wont draw to screen in Lua

Tags: text, lua, coronasdk

Looking through a few questions and answers i still am unable to find out what is wrong...

```
local myTextObject = display.newText( "Hello World!", 160, 240, "Arial", 60 )
```

This line of code - directly from the Corona Docs Guide is not displaying any text within my simulator. trying to figure out the problem i created a blank project and copy pasted this code and still nothing happens despite it being the only thing within the file.

Checking through iv used differnt fonts, used differnt methods of handling the string and still nothing will appear within the Corona Simulator - Even updating the SDK still doesnt solve this issue.

What am i doing wrong :S

thanks

Comment: Have you saved the file and restarted the simulator?

Comment: Yes multiple times and have even attempted using the sample given within the SDK but still no text :(

Comment: @Height: Is there is any error message in the console?

Answer (score 0):

```
local myText = display.newText( "Hello World!", 100, 200, native.systemFont, 16 )
myText:setFillColor( 1, 0, 0 )
```

Paste this code in the `main.lua`. Try this out it must work for sure.

Comment: sadly this doesnt work either. 

i have previously attempted to change the color of the text as well as setting the position just in case the text was off screen, but nothing seems to display Text within the Simulator - perhaps its my Simulator?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the font color?

```
text:setFillColor (200/255,0/255,2/255)
```

You said that you create a blank project so, Im expecting it as a black background, and creating text without changing the font color will make it look that it doesn't show any text

Comment: This also isnt the cause of my problem - i have attempted a variety of colors thinking that its simply not visible, but i have had no luck with this approach either... thank you though

Comment: maybe on your OS?(are you using mac?) Its strange that is doesn't show anything. Do the console say anything when you run the simulator?